# PHPUnit test always succeeds, even when I'm calling fail()

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I'm currently trying to write some basic unit tests for a php application, unfortunately the test always succeed, even if i want them to fail. I googled for many hours, but without success. Below you can find the code which succeeds on every call:

```
public function testCreateArticle()
{
     $articleRepository = RepositoryFactory::getArticleRepository();
     $this->fail();         
}
```

Test succeeds.

If I switch the statements (fail() first) the test fails, but since I need the articleRepository, I can't do any asserts at all. It just seems to return a success after the first line.

Does anyone have a clue what could be wrong?

Comment: I believe you want to use this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917909/how-to-indicate-that-a-phpunit-test-is-expected-to-fail

Comment: I don't want to mark the test as incompleted, I wan't to test the functionality delivered in the article repository. But since line two doesn't get exectued somehow, I can test whatever I want, the test will always succeed for whatever reason.

Comment: OK. Normally, I would use a mock for the test, so you could control what the factory does, and then test on that.  However, it sounds like you are trying to test the RepositoryFactory function, not the code using it.  Are you sure the code is properly returning from RepositFactory::getArticleRespository()?  Maybe check to ensure the next line is even getting executed

Comment: The code is working, at least in the project. But that is what I am trying to say, the second line does not get executed. But how is this possible, if the test still succeeds?

Comment: Have you tried a debug statement (var_dump even) to see if that prints on your PHPUnit output. Maybe try a message on either side of the fail() call to see that they both print. If they do, and PHPUnit is not finding and using the fail(), then report it as a bug.  Without the RepositoryFactory, does the fail() function work in other tests? Maybe it is something with your factory?